# how to rename a bunch of files pre-pending incrementing index at the front?

Tags: command-prompt, windows-shell

suppose i have a list of files.

```
file1.mp3
song.mp3
random.mp3
light.mp3
```

I want to rename all of them by pre-pending an index at the front.

```
1-file1.mp3
2-song.mp3
3-random.mp3
4-light.mp3
```

how can i achieve this with a batch script in windows? Thanks!